# Cannot install scipy in python 2.7

Tags: scipy, failed-installation

When i try to install SciPy, the installer starts running but says it cannot install because it cannot detect python 3.4. But as far as i know, SciPy has support for Python 2.7.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: That is simply not enough information. What exactly have you tried? What were the errors?

Comment: You likely downloaded the wrong installer file. There are several, and you need to choose the one for your Python version.

Comment: YEs, it was done.... Actually, in the SciPy page, the link was directed to the 3.4 version which downloaded automatically. I had to download the 2.7 version manually.